# Segmentation Error in character array

Tags: c

I have written this program in Linux. I assigned the character array size to 10. Upon entering up to 23 characters, the program showed no error. But on the 24th character, it showed a segmentation error. Please tell me why we can enter excess characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main ()
{
char a[10];
scanf("%s", &a);
printf("%s", a);
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &a);` is wrong, did you see any compiler warning?

Comment: no i didnt see a warning  message. by the way, whats wrong with it?

Comment: Hint: what's the type of `a` and `&a`?

Comment: Turn on warnings (by adding `-Wall` if you use gcc). If I do, I get `warning: format '%s' expects type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[10]'`

Comment: do you mean that for a character array (or string), we must use a instead of &a ?

Comment: @UtkarshSrivastava ya! you should use `a` instead of `&a`!

Comment: Yes you need to use a instead of &a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove `&` from `scanf`.Like

```
scanf("%s", a);
```

`char a[10]` allocates the array on the stack for 10 `char` only. now when you enter characters  as soon as you get out of bounds you are overwriting other useful things like the stack frame of the `scanf` call.

**This out-of-bounds behavior is undefined by the C standard,**